# Making tooltips reactive in Meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm using Bootstrap's own tooltips, which requires some initialization. Someone told me to do it like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
        $('.tooltipped').tooltip()
}
```

Then I can add tooltips by adding the class `tooltipped` and some `data`-tags, here on a Font Awesome icon:

```
<i class="tooltipped fa fa-square" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Whatever the tooltip should say"></i>
```

The problem is that these icons spawn on items as they are dynamically added, and something is keeping the tooltips from working on fresh items. It takes a full reload of the page to get them working.

Googling the issue I found two supposed solutions, none of which is working.

**The first solution** was to wrap the initializing code inside a `Meteor.defer()` function, something with which I have no experience and indeed doesn't even show up in the official documents.

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.defer(function() {
        $('.tooltipped').tooltip()
    })
}
```

This, however, doesn't seem to do anything.

**The second solution** wasn't really a solution at all, but simply a recommendation to ditch Bootstrap's tooltips and install *lookback:tooltips* but that was not a very pleasant experience at all (complicated and non-working).

So I'm left with Bootstrap and non-reactivity. Does anyone know how to make it work proper?

Comment: How are these items `dynamically added`? Could you show some code that generates the `fresh items`?

Comment: @SanderGarretsen Through a mongo `insert`...

Comment: In your example, is `myTemplate`, the template instance of a single `fresh` item? Do you have a template for a single item?

Comment: @SanderGarretsen Yes. But it's not a single item, just the "model" for them.

Comment: ok, not sure what you mean by `model`... but I posted an answer with some sample-code of what I thing your code may look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this does not work...

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each myTemplateItems}}
    <i class="tooltipped fa fa-square" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{whateverTheTooltipShoudSay}}"></i>
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  $('.tooltipped').tooltip()
})
```

The `onRendered` callback does not get triggered when an item is added to `myTemplateItems`. This is because the `myTemplate` is already rendered.

But this should work:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each myTemplateItems}}
    {{>myTemplateItem}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="myTemplateItem">
  <i class="tooltipped fa fa-square" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{whateverTheTooltipShoudSay}}"></i>
</template>

Template.myTemplateItem.onRendered(function() {
  this.$('.tooltipped').tooltip();
})
```

When a new item is added to `myTemplateItems`, a new template instance of `myTemplateItem` gets created, which you can call `onRendered` on.

Comment: It does work. I'd really like to know why because I don't quite understand!

Comment: Updated my answer answer. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I would wrap the tooptip initialisation with a document ready check just to ensure the DOM is fully ready and will therefore correctly find the CSS selector:  Template.myTemplateItem.onRendered(function() {
  $(document).ready(function(){ $('.tooltipped').tooltip(); });
})

Comment: @SanderGarretsen how "this" works in ES6 syntax e.g ()=> instead of function(){}

Comment: For me this works only on-hover. I want to display the tool tip when the focus is on the field. How do I establish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a helper in the `title` attribute. For instance, if you use the default app meteor creates in `meteor create` then you can just write:

```
<i class="tooltipped fa fa-square" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
   title="{{counter}}"> the text with the tooltip </i>
```

And you will see how the tooltip changes when the counter button is clicked. This is using a `Session` variable, which is a perfect example of a reactive data source. But other reactive data sources should work just the same, e.g., a query on a collection.

Caveat: I don't know what happens if the user hovers the item with the tooltip, i.e., in that case the tooltip may not update until the user moves the mouse away and then hovers again.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I use is when change(s) in your templates are triggered by buttons/events, you can programmatically destroy and reinitialize your tooltips in the event handlers.  This works really well if you have different versions of the same button with different tooltips/disabled settings based on some condition in your data.

Your template:

```
{{#unless exceededCapacity}}
    <a href="" id="addItemButton" class="add-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Click here to add items.">Add Item</a>
{{else}}
    <a href="" id="addItemButton" class="add-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="You cannot add any more items." disabled>Add Item</a>
{{/unless}}
```

Then your event code:

```
'click .add-item': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  

    //  Destroy the tooltips
    $('.add-item').tooltip('destroy');

    //  Code to do your work... e.g insert time

    //  Reinitialize tooltips - this could also be called in an insert callback upon success, etc.
    $('.add-item').tooltip({trigger: 'hover'});

}
```